# Cannot Upload Video (MP4) File

Tags: uploads, media-library, videos

It's a 28.8 M .mp4 file that has uploaded to another WP installation and is live. I'm trying to use the same file on a development server - a fresh install of WP with a media upload limit of 512M. Relevant php.ini setting: upload_max_filesize = 600M. These are the settings I've changed, as the initial upload limit was 16M.

I'm receiving the error: "Unexpected response from the server. The file may have been uploaded successfully. Check in the Media Library or reload the page." This occurs with any .mp4 file under the size limit.

Image files upload without error.

I have researched the issue, with all solutions pointing to the file size limit, which I seem to have addressed. I have reinstalled WP core. I've also uninstalled/reinstalled WP. The server is self-hosted, and I have root access.  Thank you all for having a look!

Edit: I am not using a security plugin, or a plugin that changes max upload size - I'm doing that directly.

Comment: did you look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59915558/wordpress-unexpected-response-from-the-server-the-file-may-have-been-uploaded

Comment: I did, and after reading again, the only thing I'm catching is that the php.ini size doesn't match (what I think is in) the functions.php. I'll try matching them.  I'm also not using any plugins for caching, security or size mods, and I'll update this in my original post. Thank you!

Comment: It was the post_max_size line. It was still set to 16M.

Answer (score 0):

The post_max_size line was still set to 16M. I set it to match upload_max_filesize and the file uploaded without error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you **upload** the video to **YouTube** or other **video upload sites**. And then embed it on your website. Unless your website has a large storage and high-performance hosting server, video will slow down your **website's loading speed**.